# how can i reduce the lag in my sshd session?

Tags: ssh, latency

I'm trying to use various ncurses programs through ssh but there's lag up/down in the sshd. I'm wondering if there are any tips like sshd config settings or tcp/ip settings that can help reduce the latency.

Answer (score 2):

The limiting factor for *bandwidth* is usually ssh's own internal buffers (see [hpn-ssh](http://www.psc.edu/networking/projects/hpn-ssh/)). However you are talking about latency. You need to have a long hard look at how much of the latency is inherent in the network and how much is down to ssh. You've not provided any information about the ssh client/server you are using. OpenSSH (and probably most other implementations) have [nagle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm) disabled by default - implying that the problems are on your network.

Assuming that you've eliminated [MTU](http://www.netheaven.com/pmtu.html) and [TCP Window scaling](http://lwn.net/Articles/92727/) issues, there's not a lot you can do about latency other than looking at dedicated links.